# Will installing .NET 1.1 or 2.0 on my computer that already has .NET 4.5 screw things up?

Tags: .net

I sometimes feel like looking at the source code as it might have been inside an assembly when it was in .NET 2.0 or .NET 1.1.

For example, the APM methods such as `FileStream.BeginRead` etc. have since .NET v4.0 been implemented using TPL but I want to see what the source code of this method was like during .NET 2.0 days or at .NET 1.1 time.

So, I would like an earlier version of the whole framework on my machine though I would not want it to replace anything in the GAC or screw up ASP.NET or IIS installations telling them that they need to use it because it was installed later than the presently existing .NET 4.5.x.

Will installing .NET 1.1 on my 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium Edition laptop be safe or will it screw things up?

Comment: What OS are you running? I don't think there's a great deal of overlap between those OSes where 1.1 works and those where 4.5 works. I *think* the only 2 common ones are Vista or Server 2008 (not R2)

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you. I am running Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium on a laptop. I have updated my question with this information.

Comment: Why do you "need" to browse the source code for a platform that's over 10 years old?

Comment: @DStanley Out of curiosity. To study, to see how things were implemented back then. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ### Compatibility and side-by-side execution
>
> If you cannot find a suitable
>   workaround for your issue, remember that the .NET Framework 4.5 runs
>   side by side with versions 1.1, 2.0, and 3.5, and is an in-place
>   update that replaces version 4. For apps that target versions 1.1,
>   2.0, and 3.5, you can install the appropriate version of the .NET Framework on the target machine to run the app in its best
>   environment. For more information about side-by-side execution, see
>   [Side-by-Side Execution in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8477k21c(v=vs.110).aspx).

But note that .NET 1.1 is not compatible with Windows 8 or later - you *might* be able to unpack the installer to get to the assemblies if you just want to decompile them, though.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any issues, since they use different CLR versions (CLR 2 in .NET 4, CLR 1 in .NET 2), libraries, Registry entries and directory installations.

The only issue I can think of regarding .NET compatibility issues is about .NET 4 and .NET 4.5, since the latter overwrites the .NET 4 when installing.

Actually, when installing some Visual Studio version, it includes several .NET versions and they work side by side without issues.